# I want to avoid extension of file to appear in drop-down menu in Rshiny.

Tags: r, shiny

I have a list of csv files that are in my subdirectory `data` of shiny app, that appear in drop-down menu. I want to avoid .csv extension to appear in the drop-down with the file name. Say one file with name `HG-U133_Plus_2.csv` should appear as `HG-U133_Plus_2` in drop-down. I use the below code for drop-down option. Thanks

On ui.r :

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "data",pattern="\\.csv$")    
selectInput('dataset',"choose platform annotation file", c("Choose file" ='',filenames)),
```

server.r:

```
dataInput <- reactive({


        if (grepl("[/\\\\]", input$dataset)) {
          stop("Invalid dataset")
        }

        read.csv(file.path("data", input$dataset))
      })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the names of the `choices` vector:

```
names(filenames) <- gsub(pattern = "\\.csv$", "", filenames)
```